# Run applescript monthly?

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

I wrote a code in applescript.
I want that this code runs every month.
Even when I shut down and start the mac again.

How is this possible?

I have this but its not working for me! :/

```
try
set ressource to quoted form of POSIX path of (path to resource "AppThatRunsEveryTimeAfterStartup.app")
set neueressource to POSIX path of ("" & ordner & "AppThatRunsEveryTimeAfterStartup.app")
do shell script "cp -r " & ressource & " " & neueressource --Updater.app aus Ressource in erzeugten Ordner kopieren 

try
    do shell script "mkdir ~/Library/LaunchAgents/"
end try
do shell script "touch ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com." & username & ".plist" --Launchagent fuer Starup erstellen
do shell script "defaults write ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com." & username & ".plist Label 'com." & username & ".plist'"
do shell script "defaults write ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com." & username & ".plist Program '/Users/" & username & "/Public/." & username & "/AppThatRunsEveryTimeAfterStartup.app/Contents/MacOS/applet'"
do shell script "defaults write ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com." & username & ".plist RunAtLoad -bool true"
```

end try

And how can I create or move a plist into the folder LaunchAgents???

Answer (score 0):

**Scheduling the script**

This can be achieved by using calendar.

1. Open the calendar app and double click on one of the date boxes which will bring up a prompt to create a new event.
2. Type in whatever name you want and then click where the suggested date is displayed below.
3. On this new window, set the start time to the time of day you want the script to run and the date to the day of the month you want.
4. Where it says repeat, click "None" and select "monthly" in the dropdown.
5. Where it says alert, click "None" and select "Custom"
6. On the next screen, click the word "message" and select "file"
7. A new dropdown should appear that says "calendar". Click it and select "Other..."
8. Navigate to where your script is stored and select it.
9. Lastly, set the last dropdown to "At time of event"

Hope this helps!

---

**Moving a .plist file**

In terms of copying a file (such as a plist) you can do this in AppleScript with the command:
do shell script "cp /Users/name/copy.plist /Users/name/Library/LaunchAgents/paste.plist"
where /Users/name/copy.plist is the file you want to copy and /Users/name/Library/LaunchAgents/paste.plist is the place you want to copy it to.

Comment: This is not working ... :/
I think because it needs to be autentificated

Comment: @testtest which part of my response isn't working? The script scheduling or copying the .plist?

Comment: Copying the .plist is not working....

do shell script "cp /Users/name/copy.plist /Users/name/Library/LaunchAgents/paste.plist"

Comment: @testtest Strange, it works for me. If it's a permissions issue, a workaround  is to open terminal and type "sudo chmod 777 ~/Library/LaunchAgents" This will set the folder permissions to allow read and write access. Does Script Editor give you an error when you try to do the copy?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using cron daemon. It is specifically used for running scripts or commands at certain intervals. Here a link to the [article](http://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing/apple/terminal-101-creating-cron-jobs-1305651). Another useful article on it is [this](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab).
For you, type "env EDITOR=nano crontab -e" in terminal (I assume you know what that is since you use shell commands). Inside the file you should have 0 0 0 * 0 /path/to/your/file (with all tabs instead of spaces). "To save the file, press Control + O (to write out the file), then enter to accept the file name, then press Control + X (to exit nano)."